# Best practice: storing user login information alongside application data

Tags: database, security

Suppose we have a table called Users which has a large amount of application data fields. 
We now want to add login information (username / password). 
Obviously it is a one to one relationship between User and LoginInformation.

From a best practice view is it preferable to mix this information with the application data or create a separate table with the User id as primary key and also foreign key into the Users table?

Does either solution make it easier to protect the login data from a security point of view?

Comment: "Obviously it is a one to one relationship between User and LoginInformation." I would argue that this is not obvious. On stackoverflow itself, for instance, you can have multiple logins associated with one user.

Comment: Point taken. In this case it is 1 to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically a separate table can be better protected, because you can limit the rights on it. But in the end, at some point you will need to read that data to be able to login.

Nevertheless, it may still be a good idea to do so. You can more safely grant every application or every part of your application access to the user table, and hide the login information so only a specific part of your can validate logins using different credentials.

After that, you can even write a separate application (like a webservice) that does authentication for you. That way, the regular application(s) don't have access to the login information at all. They just can ask the server whether a user is authenticated.

So long story short: yes, separating login information does increase the possibility to better protect that information, and adds additional benefits regarding flexibility.